# How to make a particle image bigger with a scale effect with SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit, particles

I am looking for the same effect as we have in `SpriteKit` for the emitter particles, the `scale` effect that can make a particle image bigger or smaller depending on the time. (a simple red circle for example, getting bigger and disappearing after 1 second.) I cannot find the same `scale` option as we can find in `SpriteKit`. The image can be bigger and stay bigger, but it would not change depending on the time then.

Would someone know a good way to do this?

Thanks

EDIT:

None of these attempts worked, would you know why?

```
func addParticleSceneKit(){
        println("add")
        var fire = SCNParticleSystem(named: "circle1.scnp", inDirectory: "art.scnassets/Particles")
        fire.particleSize = 5
        emitter.addParticleSystem(fire) //emitter is a SCNNode

        /*
        let bigger = SCNAction.runBlock { (node) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(1)
                fire.propertyControllers = [SCNParticlePropertySize : 10.0]
            })
        }
        emitter.runAction(bigger)
        */

        //SCNTransaction.begin()
        //SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(1)
        //fire.propertyControllers = [SCNParticlePropertySize : 10.0]
        //SCNTransaction.commit()
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow. Just wow. You've thrown a lot of code at the wall just to see what sticks, but have you looked in the documentation?

The method description for [`SCNParticlePropertyController`'s initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNParticlePropertyController_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNParticlePropertyController/controllerWithAnimation:) includes a code example that does almost exactly what you're asking for — it animates particle sizes. Reproduced here:

```
// 1. Create and configure an animation object.
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation()
animation.values = [ 0.1, 1.0, 3.0, 0.5 ]

// 2. Create a property controller from the animation object.
let sizeController = SCNParticlePropertyController(animation: animation)

// 3. Assign the controller to a particle system, associating it with a particle property.
particleSystem.propertyControllers = [ SCNParticlePropertySize: sizeController ]
```

If you only need a from size and a to size instead of keyframes, you can use a `CABasicAnimation` in step 1.

Comment: Was it so surprising? :) Like Wow? :) No, I did not look at the propertyController class, my mistake, I directly used the dictionary. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `SCNParticleSystem.ParticleProperty.size`, in iOS 10, for `SCNParticlePropertySize`

Answer (score 5):

SCNParticleSystem has properties like

```
// Specifies the initial size of the particle. Animatable.
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat particleSize;

// Specifies the initial size variation of the particle. Animatable.
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat particleSizeVariation;
```

if you need more control you can also provide your own particle property controller for the key "SCNParticlePropertySize". For example to specify the how the size should be animated over the particle life duration.

see

```
// Property controllers.
// The keys for this directionary are listed in the "Particle Properties Name" section.
// The values are instances of SCNParticlePropertyController
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *propertyControllers;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried to animate it, and set the initial size, but the image stays at the same initial value. I edited my post, could you have a look?